# eslint disables all warnings instead of one type

Tags: reactjs, eslint, warnings, eslintrc

In my react app, I have ~60 elements with mouse listeners, and without keyboard listeners.

Of course, eslint warns me about it: Visible, non-interactive elements with click handlers must have at least one keyboard listener.

I know it's a bad practice, but my command will add these listeners later, don't worry.

I decided to add a rule for eslint: created .eslintrc.js in the root directory, and added the following code:

```
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    extends: "react-app",
    "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": "off",
  },
}
```

After project was rebuilt, ALL the warnings disappeared from console (include unused vars, missing dependencies, etc). Okay, I removed .eslintrc.js and added the rule to package.json:

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "rules": {
      "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": "off"
    }
  }
```

The same effect after project rebuild. I removed this rule, then I created .eslintrc.json file in the root directory, and put there the following code:

```
{
  "plugins": ["jsx-a11y"],
  "rules": {
    "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": "off"
  }
}
```

After rebuild ALL the warnings disappeared from my console again.

What am I doing wrong? How can I remove only warnings of this type and leave the others?